# Skip automatically pop up of "Open as read-only?"

Tags: vba, excel

I use at the moment the following command to open a set of workbooks one by one:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=file, Password:=""
```

Normally the files are `not` open in `read-only` mode, this is what I want. But for some files, the previous line pops up the following window:

[image]

In this case, I still want to open the file (cliking `Yes`), even thought that will be `read-only`. Could anyone tell me how I could automatize this choice by command of VBA, instead of clicking?

Comment: Does `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` work?

Comment: But I may have other kind of Alerts that I don't want to skip...

Comment: turn it off before opening and then right back on after?

Comment: Do these other alerts come up as you're opening the workbook?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `ReadOnly:=False` in the call to `Workbooks.Open`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excel has a number of "alerts" that you can shut off by setting `Application.DisplayAlerts` to `False`.

Set it to `False` before you open the workbook, and then back to `True` after the workbook is opened, so you will not eliminate any other subsequent alerts.

The specific *Open as read-only?* alert comes up on some workbooks because these workbooks were last saved with the "read-only recommended" checkbox checked. Re-saving these workbooks without the "read-only recommended" setting will stop prompting for read-only, but that may not be what you want.

However, the `Workbooks.Open` method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx)) has a `ReadOnly` parameter which you can specify:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=file, Password:="", ReadOnly:=False
```

This should open the workbook in write-enabled mode, even if it was saved with the "read-only recommended" setting - as far as I remember, specifying this argument will skip the *Open as read-only?* alert and go with the setting you've provided...

Comment: Since newer Excel versions `ReadOnly:=False` still promts the "read-only recommended" but there is a `IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True` Flag now to Ignore only this prompt (`Application.DisplayAlerts` to `False` hides more than this prompt only).

Answer (score 3):

Just want to point out that the suggested answer is not correct:

Directly from MSDN about the ReadOnly Flag:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835182.aspx

> **True** to open the document as read-only. **This argument doesn't override
>   the read-only recommended setting on a saved document**. For example, if
>   a document has been saved with read-only recommended turned on,
>   setting the ReadOnly argument to False will not cause the file to be
>   opened as read/write.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ReadOnly` argument:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=file, Password:="", ReadOnly:=True
```

the message won't pop-up then.

Comment: Simple, but true, unfortunately, changing things like `TWOPAGESONONE` requires read/write even if I'm not editing the document..