# vba open file regardless of being used by another user

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Error Screenshot]

I am trying to open workbook in vba using the following code

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:="FilePath"
```

is there a way to open the file in read only mode without manually pressing the popup?

Comment: try .. [VBA Open without prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999418/skip-automatically-pop-up-of-open-as-read-only)

Comment: possible duplicate of [vba Open excel when File is used by another user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913111/vba-open-excel-when-file-is-used-by-another-user)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the following code

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=LDSP, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
```